# Why dosen't the parent thread calling pthread_yield make child threads run first?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Here are my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>

void *helper(void *arg)
{
    printf("HELPER\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &helper, NULL);
    pthread_yield();
    // sched_yield();
    printf("MAIN\n");
    
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Using *pthread_yield()* or *sched_yield()*, the output is always:

```
MAIN
HELPER
```

Two facts I have learnt make me to presume ***HELPER*** would be printed before ***MAIN***:

1. Calling *pthread_yield* causes the calling thread to relinquish the CPU. **The thread is placed at the end of the run queue for its static priority and another thread is scheduled to run.** If the calling thread is the only thread in the highest priority list at that time, it will continue to run.
2. The child thread is created with the same priority as the parent.

What may be the reason for ***HELPER*** is printed after ***MAIN***?

Comment: Threads don't run in any well-defined order, they run *in parallel* with each other.  Therefore unless you synchronize their behavior, it's up to the OS what order the threads will run in, `pthread_yield()` calls notwithstanding.

Comment: The documentation for `sched_yield()` (POSIX standard) and `pthread_yield()` (non-standard) comes with lots of warnings about how it's meant for use in certain real-time scheduler situations and that using it in a process with a normal scheduler is not very well defined. It *may* do what you want, but it's equally valid to not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether `pthread_yield` can/will do what you expect (i.e. make the HELPER run first) depends on the system scheduler being used and how it's configured.

In general you can only expect (or rather hope for) such behavior on systems with very simple schedulers. A modern (Linux) system will - per default - use a more complex scheduling so you can't rely on `pthread_yield` to synchronize the order of execution.

And even if MAIN was stopped and the HELPER was started, the HELPER could be preempted before doing the printing. Or how about multi-core CPUs? What if both threads ran in parallel? Which would do the print first?

So - No, `pthread_yield` is not the tool for syncronizing threads.

For more on scheduling read:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html

Here you can read about a number of system calls that you can use for getting information about the scheduler and configure the scheduler.

But in order to control the thread execution order, you shouldn't rely on controlling the scheduler. Implement your own control, e.g. by using a `mutex`